# vue.js 2 h3 tag in a tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

Here is my code. I don't know why I can't click h3 & h5 tag to open a new page on web, but when I click on img tag it works. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

```js
<div class="item">    
    <a  v-bind:href="brand.channel.parent_channel.name_en + '/' + brand.channel.name_en +'/articles/' + brand.id">
  <div class="module_img">
   <img :src="brand.logo" :alt="brand.title"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="dotdot">{{ brand.title }}</h3>
  <h5 class="dotdot">{{ brand.brief }}</h5>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @click event for anchor tag
Example:

```
<div>
      <a @click="openGoogle()">
        <div>
          <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
        </div>
        <h3>john</h3>
        <h5>doe</h5>
      </a>
    </div>
```

and in methods:

```
openGoogle(){
      window.open('http://google.com');
    },
```

you can pass data through method parameters

Comment: It's still not working on clicking h3 tag. Can you help me to figure me out ? Thanks you. Here is my latest code. https://jsbin.com/sacorizupe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try to add style `display: inline-block` in `<a>` tag.

Comment: It's not working. I have also try to delete all of tags in a tag except h3 but  It is still not working.

Comment: I just run your lastest code in my environment,but no problem with click h3 and h5.

Comment: @@ It's very weird. Maybe It's disabled by another javascript. Thanks you for that let me know my JavaScript code which is corrected.